# "Decorators-legacy" isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql-js, typescript-decorator

I am sharing an object type between backend and frontend. I use it as a validator and when Graphql exchanges data between client and server it only sends the data in these object types.

This is an AuthenticationInput object:

```
    import { Field, InputType } from "type-graphql";
    @InputType()
export class AuthenticationInput {

    @Field({nullable: false})
    email: string;

    @Field({nullable: false})
    password: string
}
```

This exists both on the backend and frontend. On the backend which is an apollo server running on graphQL there's no issue. However, on the client side I get this error:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled
```

I do have "experimentalDecorators": true in my tsconfig.json. I'm not sure what to do. I get the error for both Field and InputType.

Running with webpack, next.js, react, typescript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that these configurations cannot be run on the client and are not compatible with React.

Comment: Is there any solution?